# Setting state before render react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, state

So I'm writing a simple App that looks like the following: 3 different color buttons that once pressed change the background of the parent div they're housed in and when pressed again, change the background back to the original.

The background change is an animation that originates from the button itself (using clip-path circle css) and after feeding the correct coordinates to the style, it does the job.

Problem is, every new click on a button doesn't set the state before the render and so the green background originates from the blue background button because those are the old coordinates and currently the state.

I've read that in react there is no before, only after and I've looking into the componentwillmount function but that was advised me not to set state in it so I'm staying clear of it.

Is there any way to fix this issue? Or is this just something react cant' do?

The following is my App code (the useEffect bit is just so that the background doesn't originate from coordinates 0 0 which is the default in the css and sets the state based off of certain coordinates).

```
import './App.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [box, setBox] = useState({active: false, color: '', left: '', top: ''});
  // const [globalCoords, setGlobalCoords] = useState({x: 0, y: 0})
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowMouseMove = event => {
      if ((event.x < 350 && event.x > 250) && (event.y > 250 && event.y < 350)) {
        setBox({left: '300px', top: '300px'})
      } else if ((event.x < 1600 && event.x > 1500) && (event.y > 50 && event.y < 150)) {
        setBox({left: '1550px', top: '100px'})
      } else if ((event.x < 1100 && event.x > 1000) && (event.y > 500 && event.y < 600)) {
        setBox({left: '1050px', top: '550px'})
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleWindowMouseMove);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleWindowMouseMove);
    };
  }, []);
  // console.log(globalCoords);

  return (
    <section>
      <div style={{'--color': box.color, '--left': box.left, '--top': box.top}} className={box.active ? 'box active' : 'box'}></div>
      <div style={{backgroundColor: box.color === 'orange' ? 'black' : ''}} onClick={() => setBox({active: !box.active, color: 'orange', left: '300px', top: '300px'})} className={box.active ? (box.color === 'orange' ? 'pulse1' : 'pulse1 disable') : 'pulse1'}>
        <span style={{'--i': 0}}></span>
        <span style={{'--i': 1}}></span>
        <span style={{'--i': 2}}></span>
        <span style={{'--i': 3}}></span>
      </div>
      <div style={{backgroundColor: box.color === 'turquoise' ? 'black' : ''}} onClick={() => setBox({active: !box.active, color: 'turquoise', left: '1550px', top: '100px'})} className={box.active ? (box.color === 'turquoise' ? 'pulse2' : 'pulse2 disable') : 'pulse2'}>
        <span style={{'--i': 0}}></span>
        <span style={{'--i': 1}}></span>
        <span style={{'--i': 2}}></span>
        <span style={{'--i': 3}}></span>
      </div>
      <div style={{backgroundColor: box.color === 'red' ? 'black' : ''}} onClick={() => setBox({active: !box.active, color: 'red', left: '1050px', top: '550px'})} className={box.active ? (box.color === 'red' ? 'pulse3' : 'pulse3 disable') : 'pulse3'}>
        <span style={{'--i': 0}}></span>
        <span style={{'--i': 1}}></span>
        <span style={{'--i': 2}}></span>
        <span style={{'--i': 3}}></span>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The following is my css:

```
:root {
  --i: 0;
  --top: 0;
  --left: 0;
  --color: transparent;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #102e37;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--color);
  transition: clip-path 1s linear;
  clip-path: circle(0% at var(--left) var(--top));
}

.box.active {
  clip-path: circle(150% at var(--left) var(--top));
}

.pulse1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 250px;
  left: 250px;
  animation: intro 5s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.pulse1 span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  opacity: .8;
  animation: pulseAnimate 4s ease-out infinite;
  animation-delay: calc(1s * var(--i));
}

@keyframes pulseAnimate {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}

.pulse2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: turquoise;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  left: 1500px;
  animation: intro 5s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.pulse2 span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  opacity: .8;
  animation: pulseAnimate 4s ease-out infinite;
  animation-delay: calc(1s * var(--i));
}

.pulse3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 500px;
  left: 1000px;
  animation: intro 5s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.pulse3 span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  opacity: .8;
  animation: pulseAnimate 4s ease-out infinite;
  animation-delay: calc(1s * var(--i));
}

.pulse1.disable {
  animation: seconds .8s both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.pulse2.disable {
  animation: seconds .8s both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.pulse3.disable {
  animation: seconds .8s both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes seconds {
  0% {
      opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
      opacity: 0;
  }
} 

@keyframes intro {
  0% {
      opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I see neither a "green background" nor a "blue button" here.

Comment: Likely we do need to see here the circle animation code and how its fed in and triggered

Comment: blue and red* (turquoise is a type of blue)

Comment: Ok I'll add the css, it's just 100+ lines

Comment: Ah i see, its the classnames? Never mind, thats enough info

Comment: Do you not want to animate from green to blue? What do you actually want to happen??

Comment: I want the red to animate from the red and blue from blue etc. Now what's happening is if I click the blue right after clicking the red, it'll animate from the red because red's coordinates are still the state

Comment: Ok I fully understand now. The div with the vars applied is an overlay with the button ripple type animation

Comment: Correct. To add onto my previous statement, the code how it is currently is fine, as in if i slowly move my mouse over the buttons and hover for a second so that the document can correctly process the logic and set the state based on the coordinates, then it's fine. But any other user won't know to do that and so they'll quickly try and click the button and the animation will originate from different coordinates because it was done too quickly, if that makes any sense

Comment: Yep got it. I have an idea, give me some mins

Comment: Of course, thanks

Comment: Almost there, bare with me lol

Comment: No rush, making my own edits

Comment: Aha Ive figured out the state setting (which can be fixed with refs, ive done that, is not your only issue). When the position changes of the item in the background, position is animated also.

Comment: Can fix. need a  bit more time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248087/discussion-between-ether-and-adam-thomas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import "./styles.css";

import { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [box, setBox] = useState({
    active: false,
    color: "",
    left: "",
    top: ""
  });
  const [key, setKey] = useState(0);
  // const [globalCoords, setGlobalCoords] = useState({x: 0, y: 0})

  const nextBoxCoords = useRef({ left: "", top: "" });
  console.log(nextBoxCoords, box);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleWindowMouseMove = (event) => {
      if (event.x < 350 && event.x > 250 && event.y > 250 && event.y < 350) {
        nextBoxCoords.current = {
          left: "300px",
          top: "300px"
        };
      } else if (
        event.x < 1600 &&
        event.x > 1500 &&
        event.y > 50 &&
        event.y < 150
      ) {
        nextBoxCoords.current = {
          left: "1550px",
          top: "100px"
        };
      } else if (
        event.x < 1100 &&
        event.x > 1000 &&
        event.y > 500 &&
        event.y < 600
      ) {
        nextBoxCoords.current = {
          left: "1050px",
          top: "550px"
        };
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleWindowMouseMove);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleWindowMouseMove);
    };
  }, []);
  // console.log(globalCoords);

  const commit = ({ color, active }) => {
    setKey((prev) => prev + 1);
    setBox((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      left: nextBoxCoords.current.left,
      top: nextBoxCoords.current.top
    }));

    setTimeout(() => {
      setBox((prev) => ({
        left: nextBoxCoords.current.left,
        top: nextBoxCoords.current.top,
        color,
        active
      }));
    }, 0);
  };

  return (
    <section key={key}>
      <div
        style={{
          "--color": box.color,
          "--left": box.left,
          "--top": box.top
        }}
        className={box.active ? "box active" : "box"}
      ></div>
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: box.color === "orange" ? "black" : "" }}
        onClick={() => {
          commit({
            active: !box.active,
            color: "orange"
          });
        }}
        className={
          box.active
            ? box.color === "orange"
              ? "pulse1"
              : "pulse1 disable"
            : "pulse1"
        }
      >
        <span style={{ "--i": 0 }}></span>
        <span style={{ "--i": 1 }}></span>
        <span style={{ "--i": 2 }}></span>
        <span style={{ "--i": 3 }}></span>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: box.color === "turquoise" ? "black" : "" }}
        onClick={() => {
          commit({
            active: !box.active,
            color: "turquoise"
          });
        }}
        className={
          box.active
            ? box.color === "turquoise"
              ? "pulse2"
              : "pulse2 disable"
            : "pulse2"
        }
      >
        <span style={{ "--i": 0 }}></span>
        <span style={{ "--i": 1 }}></span>
        <span style={{ "--i": 2 }}></span>
        <span style={{ "--i": 3 }}></span>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: box.color === "red" ? "black" : "" }}
        onClick={() => {
          commit({
            active: !box.active,
            color: "red"
          });
        }}
        className={
          box.active
            ? box.color === "red"
              ? "pulse3"
              : "pulse3 disable"
            : "pulse3"
        }
      >
        <span style={{ "--i": 0 }}></span>
        <span style={{ "--i": 1 }}></span>
        <span style={{ "--i": 2 }}></span>
        <span style={{ "--i": 3 }}></span>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This hacks around with resetting the animation to get the position where it needs to be, and avoids slow state updates by using refs.